# jQuery add/remove class only works once

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a small/(strange?) problem with some basic jQuery. Inside an HTML form i have two elements:

```
<label for="service-webdesign">
     <input type="checkbox" name="service-web" id="service-webdesign" value="Webdesign" />
     <span id="service-webdesign-span">Webdesign</span>
</label>
<label for="service-SEO" title="Search Engine Optimization">
     <input type="checkbox" name="service-web" id="service-SEO" value="SEO" />
     <span class="service-SEO-span">SEO</span>
</label>
```

Now, what I want to do is add/remove a class called "active" to style either of these elements different when they are hit. Here is the jQuery to achieve that:

```
$('#service-webdesign').click(function(){
    if($('#service-webdesign-span').hasClass('active')){
        $('#service-webdesign-span').removeClass('active')
        } else ($('#service-webdesign-span').addClass('active'))
    });

$('#service-SEO').click(function(){
    if($('#service-SEO-span').hasClass('active')){
        $('#service-SEO-span').removeClass('active')
        } else ($('#service-SEO-span').addClass('active'))
    });
```

Although both of them are identical (functioning wise), only the first one is working as expected. I am sure that is has nothing to do with their order though, since swapping the jQuery around doesn't make any difference. I have started with jQuery only just yesterday, so I probably lack the ability to see through this behaviour.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `service-SEO-span` is a class but `service-webdesign-span` is an id and you're targeting them both as if they were ids.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I can see that now - thanks again :)

Comment: from next time please use a 'jsfiddle' too, with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

And you should use the right selector as Juhana already mentioned in the comments!

```
$('#service-webdesign-span').toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

service-SEO-span is a class but service-webdesign-span is an id and you're targeting them both as if they were ids.